# Only the first entry from database is displayed

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have 2 php files that retrieve a BLOB image from mysql DB. My DB has stored a couple of different images, as i try to display them on the browser, only the first image is displayed multiple times, for example: The DB table has stored 5 images, the browser is going to display the first image 5 times. 
here is a snippet from my main php file:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM images";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo "<tr><td>";
echo " <img src=load_pic.php?id=".$row["id"]." id='img' width='100' height='100'></a>";
echo "</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>"
```

and the php file that gets the images "load_pic.php"

```
 $q="select * from images";
   $rec=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($q));
   $data=$rec['image'];
   header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
  header("Content-type: image/".$rec['type']);
  echo $data;
```

Comment: You give the same `id='img'` to all the images. IDs are required to be unique. I'm not sure why this is causing the behavior you see, but you need to fix it anyway.

Comment: @Barmar the id='img' is just the identifier for all images I use, its for styling

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use a class for styling.

Comment: Noted @Barmar. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `load_pic.php` script is not using the `id` parameter. It should be:

```
$q = "select * from images where id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```